# Can Mac OS X Messages support more than one apple id?

Tags: macos, messages

I have two Apple IDs, one for work and one personal. My iPhone's Messages settings are bound to my work id. When it receives messages, they pop up on my work computer pretty as you please.

I would like that to happen on my home computer too. If I open **Messages > Preferences > Accounts** on my home computer, I see my home Apple ID listed (along with AIM and Bonjour). I would like to add my work Apple ID as well.

When I click on **+**, I'm offered Google, Yahoo, Aol, and "other" as my choices. And under "other", the choices are "AIM", "Jabber", and "Yahoo"

I *was* able to add my work account under **Settings > Accounts**, but there doesn't seem to be a way to connect that to Messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, this is not possible. You can add multiple E-Mail addresses to one AppleID (System Preferences -> iCloud -> Account Details -> Contact) , but you cannot use multiple AppleIDs for iMessage on one user account on a Mac.

Comment: Correct, the best alternative that I would recommend is to create a new user account for the work Apple ID.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can. Go to settings>iCloud>account-details>contact. I hope it will help you

Comment: What do we do in those settings? This might allow more ways to reach to me, but second account?

Comment: This is incorrect as an answer.

Answer (score -2):

You can try going to Messages.app's Preferences (Messages > Preferences) from the menu bar.

Within it there should be a tab 'Accounts' for you to connect your work account to iMessage.

If your account appears greyed out, click it and check 'Enable this account'.

Comment: Yes, but can I add a *second* account?

Comment: You might be able add a different Apple ID account from within a new user.